# How to find Index Number of this array value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

```js
const options = [
{_id: "0175", name: "Ahnaf"},
{_id: "8555", name: "Abir"},
{_id: "8795", name: "Book"},
]
```

now how to get index of _id = 8795 ??
It means how I can get the ***index*** number to get this object `{_id: "8795", name: "Book"}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const options = [
{_id: "0175", name: "Ahnaf"},
{_id: "8555", name: "Abir"},
{_id: "8795", name: "Book"},
]

const index = options.findIndex(e => e._id==="8795");

console.log(index);
```

Comment: @taslimkd what's the issue?

Comment: i can not explain it here how can i sent picture here

Comment: I have included photo , you can understand the issue now..

Comment: You need to convert the ``ObjectId`` to a ``String`` when comparing, something like: ``e._id.toString()``. You can research this more depending on the technology you're using

Comment: @taslimkd Have you logged both values? Is the actually within the array? Or is it showing `-1` because there is no element containing the provided id? You can implicitly convert values by using `==` instead of `===`, so no reason to call `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need use combination of find and findIndex to find the index you are looking for.

```
const options = [
  {_id: "0175", name: "Ahnaf"},
  {_id: "8555", name: "Abir"},
  {_id: "8795", name: "Book"},
  ]

const foundObj = options.find((option) => option._id === "8555")
const index = options.findIndex((option, index) => {
  if(typeof foundObj !== "undefined" && option._id === foundObj._id) {
    return index
  }else
  return null
} )

console.log('index', index);
```